# How to serve Static Folder files in script tag - Django

Tags: django

I am creating a project where i create a files dynamically and store those file in staticfiles folder

But when i am accessing this file it is showing file in browser

```
http://localhost:8000/static/rest_framework/css/bootstrap.min.css
```

But when i trying to access file which i have created and stored in `staticfiles/bot_js`

```
http://localhost:8000/static/bot_js/cfe96a9a-dc84-4127-9b00-0411b7b3288e.js
```

It is showing `Page not Found`

I want this file to hosted on my website serve as script file for different website, like this

```
<script src="http://localhost:8000/static/bot_js/cfe96a9a-dc84-4127-9b00-0411b7b3288e.js"></script>
```

But it is giving me `Page not found (404)`. How can i serve this file for different website.

settings.py

```
# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Add these new lines
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '../frontend/build/static/'),
)

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, if you're still interested I have a solution for the question you deleted a few minutes ago. https://pastebin.com/0T1c0wY8

Answer (score -1):

in production mode you should use these settings

```
STATIC_URL = 'https://YOUR_URL/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'static/'
```

Comment: How to that thing in developement, because from same folder i am able to access file, but i same i have kept my own static file is given page not found

Answer (score -1):

Add below in your settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Now go to your project urls.py and add following urlpatterns:

```
urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^media/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}), 
    url(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', serve,{'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT}),
    ]
```

Finally add this line below urlpatterns:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

P.S> If you want to serve static files in production and using empheral server as heroku you will need whitenoise installed and configure it for serving which is not recommended as it impacts website performance